# Зависает программа при вставки в фрейм xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
var fra = new Frame();

fra.Source = new Uri("UserControl2.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

`UserControl2.xaml` типа `Controls:MetroWindow` ( `MahApps.Metro.1.0.0.0` )

Но если `UserControl2.xaml` типа `UserControl` то фрейм работает

CS:

```
public partial class UserControl2 : MetroWindow
```

UserControl2.xaml:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                  xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
                  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                  xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"

                  WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" EnableDWMDropShadow="True"

...
                  >
```

Comment: Класс логики взаимодействия с UserControl1.xaml наследуется от MetroWindow?

Comment: да UserControl2 : MetroWindow